# Google Play - where is the link for testing Closed test track releases? "The link will be shown here when you publish your app."

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have an app that I'm trying to release to testers on Google Play.

I've done this before but Google keeps changing the developer console and I'm not sure if I'm missing a step.

I have published the app on a closed track. It went through review and seems to be ready:

[image]

Cool. So I set up a list of email addresses for my testers. But the place where there should be a link for them to access the app has no link:

[image]

It says 'will be available when published'. Huh? It's been published on the Closed track for hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to release on the "Internal Testing" track first and then you will see the link will show up.

Comment: Well that's stupid. Thanks.